# How to delete the current class instance using a member function of the same class

Tags: c++, class, instance

In the following code, I made my constructor and destructor private and created my own instantiation and deletion functions. But when I call the `Delete()` function, the `delete this` statement inside it seems to remove the object but not notify the compiler so it thinks the object still exists. I thought it would be a good idea to set the pointer to null or zero so I put a `this = 0` before the delete statement but it didn't work at all. What should I put inside the `Delete()` function in order to completely delete the object and its pointer?

```
class MyClass
{
private:
  MyClass() {}
 ~MyClass() {}
public:
  static MyClass *Instantiate()
  {
    MyClass *inst = new MyClass;
    return inst;
  }
  void Delete()
  {
    delete this;
  }
};

int main()
{
  MyClass *inst1 = MyClass::Instantiate();
  inst1->Delete();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "but not notify the compiler so it thinks the object still exists" - What makes you say this?

Comment: @stfrabbit Because I can't reuse the object name

Comment: Please remove the 'This question may already have an answer here' label. My question is not related to the question you mentioned.

Comment: @MohammadSanei: that banner will be removed when the (erroneous) votes expire. And only you can see it, it's not displayed for other users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you didn't explicitly express it, I believe you're wondering why `inst1` is not `NULL` after invoking `Delete()`. If so, consider this:

With `inst1->Delete();` you successfully delete the object `inst1` pointed to. However, the pointer `inst1` remains unchanged. It only points somewhere in memory that is no longer a valid instance of `MyClass`.

Also it is extremely uncommon for a member function to call `delete this`, though syntactically and semantically there's nothing wrong with your example.

Comment: Yes, that's it! How should I empty the pointer? (since `this = 0` doesn't work)

Comment: You cannot set the pointer inst1 to NULL because your instance of MyClass does not know about it.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this. Pointers to the object need to be managed externally, as the object itself does not have access to them (`this` is a local, self-referencing pointer and does not represent anything else than that.)

If you wanted to keep track of the pointers automatically, you would use a smart pointer class (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer#C.2B.2B_smart_pointers). But since you made the dtor private, you lose that ability. You can still write your own smart pointer class, of course.